# I have a word2vec embedding - now what?

Tags: neural-network, keras, nlp, word2vec

I've always relied on the Keras embedding layer for my NLP work. But for my latest project I want to use a custom embedding layer. I have gone through the steps to create a word2vec file but now what? Can someone provide an example of how I can replace the Keras embedding layer with my own layer when constructing a model?

Comment: lol'ed at the name of the post )

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure, you have the same vocabulary in your word2file and in your Keras code. If you [Keras `Tokenizer`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer), you can simply call [`fit_on_texts`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer#fit_on_texts) with the text actually being the vocabulary.

Load your word embeddings as numpy matrix (just read all the numbers and then call `np.array`).

When creating the [`Embedding` layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Embedding), call `set_weights` and set the loaded matrix and set `trainable` to `False`.

You can find more at [Keras blog](https://blog.keras.io/using-pre-trained-word-embeddings-in-a-keras-model.html) but I am not sure how up to date it is because it is from 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Before, I have implemented a downloaded embbeding using Keras' `Embedding` package:

```
from keras.layers import Embedding

embedding_layer = Embedding(
          num_words,
          EMBEDDING_DIM,
          weights=[embedding_matrix],
          input_length=MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH,
          trainable=False
        )
```